# Trying to find and store specific data within specific element names in xml?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I have an element called …in xml file, and I am trying to loop through the xml file and find that element and store the data between the element?

I have tried to find the element name and store the next 7 lines within the elements then find the next milestone element and do the same?

[Here is an example of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWCq5.png)

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I cannot seem to get the child elements of Milestone and store them

Comment: Please post your xml sample.